# parsing JSON using GSON that has arrays

Tags: android, gson

I've used GSON to retrieve a simple piece of JSON that didn't include arrays, and I placed them into a list of objects:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<SingleEvent>>(){}.getType();  
List<SingleEvent> events = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, listType);
```

SingleEvent is the class I created and just included simple string variables.

Now, I want to create an object that can take Arrays from JSON strings.

```
[{"ticketmaster":"http:\/\/www.ticketmaster.ca","images":["http:\/\/www.example.com\/sites\/default\/files\/imagecache\/gallery\/SNW_4.jpg","http:\/\/www.example.com\/sites\/default\/files\/imagecache\/gallery\/AB.jpg","http:\/\/www.example.com\/sites\/default\/files\/imagecache\/gallery\/L5Y.jpg","http:\/\/www.example.com\/sites\/default\/files\/imagecache\/gallery\/TOS.jpg"]}]
```

So, in my object that will hold this data I just made a variable like this:

```
private ArrayList images;
```

I get a warning, but I'm sure how to handle incoming json arrays.

Comment: what's the warning you're receiving?  Possibly need to set images as ArrayList<String>?

Answer (score 0):

But what if you can parse the same JSON response using native classes?

Here is a simple try:

```
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("Your JSON String");
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("images");

    for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("=====> Image at index "+i+"==>"+array.getString(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```